# FirstOrDefault not supported in EF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I am using EF and when I use FirstOrDefault on a table I get an error saying that it is not supported.  I am making the call over WCF.  Is this the issue?  Why is it not supported?  Why must I do a

```
Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of just

```
FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `FirstOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable`